# docker can't find mountend socket of the docker command

Tags: python, docker

I have a container with the base image python. The containers job is to execute a python script, the relevant part to this question is here:

```py
client = docker.from_env()
output = client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest", "echo hello world")
print (output)
```

I mount the socket of the docker in the container at startup:

```sh
docker run -tv /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -ti python_docker
```

But everytime I run the container I get following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker': 'docker'
```

I've tried to see if the script is at fault but when it is run outside of a container it works prefectly.

The library I am using for running containers in python:
https://pypi.org/project/docker/

And the dockerfile of the container:

```
FROM python
MAINTAINER jocomol
ADD ./run_container.py .
RUN pip3 install colorful docker
CMD python3 ./run_container.py
```

Comment: What Docker library are you using? (from which you create `docker` object) you are probably missing docker binaries in your image even tough the socket is mounted

Comment: @PierreB. I‘ve added the library in the Question. Wich binaries would be needed?

Comment: Add your Dockerfile as well please

Comment: @PierreB. I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. All I did was just mount the Docker binary aswell.

```sh
docker run -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -ti python_docker
```